# Getting error while creating react project Aborting installation errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'spawn'

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app, spawn

Getting the following error when creating react app

```
E:\React>create-react-app ecomerce

Creating a new React app in E:\React\ecomerce.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
    at C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting ecomerce/ from E:\React
Done.
```

Comment: Try performing `npm cache clean --force` & then create the app

Comment: when i m runing npm cache clean --force i will get npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. how can i run this command

Comment: @reebasiddiqui That is not an error. It is information, making sure that you are aware you have passed `--force`, and it is doing its "force" job by disabling certain protections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 10, at that time I installed panda antivirus, after that my visual studio code became very slow, and the error occurred. I have done several ways but there is no change. then I tried to uninstall the antivirus. And finally the error is no longer, and my pc is not slow anymore.

Comment: Could you please add more details? Which antivirus software? Why do you believe it was related to antivirus? Was it definitely the same error? Do you have any other information about your investigation?

Comment: I'm using windows 10, at that time I installed panda antivirus, after that my visual studio code became very slow, and the error occurred. I have done several ways but there is no change. then I tried to uninstall the antivirus. And finally the error is no longer, and my pc is not slow anymore.

Comment: I recommend an [edit] to add this information to the answer itself so that people will understand how & whether your answer can solve their problem.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. Sorry, I'm a new user here.